# Custom Server Control with array of check boxes in asp.net doesn't main checkboxs state

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, custom-server-controls

I've created a server control that renders a list of check boxes.
The problem is that when I check some of the checkboxes and postback form all the check boxes gets unchecked.
Here is my server control class:

```
public class WeekControl : WebControl
{
    public bool ShowCheckBoxs { get; set; }

    public WeekControl()
    {
        ShowCheckBoxs = true;
        Table = new Table();
        Table.ID = "table1";
        CheckBoxes = new CheckBox[7, 4];
        Table.CssClass = "weekly";
    }

    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            TableRow tr = new TableRow();
            Table.Rows.Add(tr);
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            {
                TableCell tc = new TableCell();
                tr.Cells.Add(tc);
                if (ShowCheckBoxs)
                {
                    CheckBoxes[i, j] = new CheckBox();
                    CheckBoxes[i, j].ID = "ch" + i.ToString() + j.ToString();
                    tc.Controls.Add(CheckBoxes[i, j]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public CheckBox[,] CheckBoxes;
    public Table Table;
    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {

        Controls.Add(Table);
        ChildControlsCreated = true;
        base.CreateChildControls();
    }


}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps `CreateChildControls` comes after the step that deserializes the viewstate.  Have you tried moving `Controls.Add(Table)` to `OnInit`?

You might find the [MSDN article on ASP.NET page life cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) an interesting read.  It mentions CreateChildControls only in the comment section.

The only comment on the [CreateChildControls documentation page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.createchildcontrols.aspx#1) cautions against overriding the method.  If it helps you, buy [Roy Soliver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/community/user/1617229.aspx) a beer :)